# How to show a overlay progressBar in bottom of activity

Tags: android

I'm new in Android and trying to build a news app, where I'm facing issue with progressbar(circle). The activity contains a `MultiSwipeRefreshLayout` and `RecyclerViews`. As it's a news app, I wanted to add infinity scroll. So, I want to add a progressBar in the bottom of recyclerview. Unfortunately the progressBar is not visible unless I wrap them into a ScrollView. Otherhand, when I'm adding ScrollView it's not scrolling properly. When you just start the app and scroll down to get more news its sometime working good, but, when I'm trying see old news(scrolled up), the swipe refresh layout starts refreshing..

I'm attaching xml resource of that activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCategories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:minHeight="15dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/adsense" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewHeadlines"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:minWidth="300dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <com.khabarsamay.khabarsamay.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewNews"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/ProgressBarBottom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </com.khabarsamay.khabarsamay.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `RelativeLayout`

```
<com.khabarsamay.khabarsamay.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewNews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/ProgressBarBottom"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" // for showing it to the bottom
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.khabarsamay.khabarsamay.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: One thing I noticed, once the ProgressBar is visible, if I scroll up it still showing in the bottom. Is there any way by which it will always stick to the possible of last element of RecyclerView?

Comment: add your progressbar as footer of recyclerview.. you cant find tutorial for that online.

Comment: if you need to add `header` or `footer` use `listview`

Comment: @VishalYadav you can add `header` and `footer` in `RecyclerView` as well

Comment: programmatically we can add